# vSphere API host turn OFF/ON

Tags: api, vmware, virtualization, vsphere, vcenter

It's possible to turn on/off host using vSphere API using vCenter?

I can't find suitable function on VMware API or some example in pythonor other language.

Answer (score 1):

You can power off the host using the vSphere API using the HostSystem Object.

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/ → Managed Object Types → Search for **Host System** → Click **Local Methods** at the top.

There are methods called **ShutdownHost_Task** or **PowerDownHostToStandby_Task**.